# Monodromy theorem on manifolds

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

On a special manifold $\mathbb{C}$ the well known [Monodromy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem#Monodromy_theorem) holds. My question is if it holds for any complex 2-dimensional manifolds as well?

**More concretely:**

**I can show:** the first (more trivial) part namely that the analytic continuation does not depend on chosen cover of a given curve.

**It is left to show:** that if we assume that analytic continuation exists along any curve in $M$ and $H: I \times I \rightarrow M$ is a homotopy between $H(0,\cdot)$ and $H(1,\cdot)$ than value obtained at $H(0,1)=H(1,1)$ is the same.

I would appreciate a precise approach (since I have actually a problem in detailing the proof: my approach is to show that we have a well defined function on $H(I \times I)$ by considering the times for which we have a well defined function on $H(I\times [0,s])$ ) or reference.